# Word for a prediction about the past

Tags: single-word-requests

When the weatherman makes a prediction, we call it a "forecast"
When economists make forecasts about the current condition of the economy, we call those estimates "nowcasts"
If a scientist makes an estimate about something in the past (ex. the cost of a candy bar in 1850), what do we call it?

Comment: In the case of people mocking purported prognosticators who only seem to "have predicted" an event *after* it has occurred, the common barb is *postdiction* (viz Nostradamus).

Comment: Or perhaps a _postgnostication_.

Comment: *Who* calls it a 'nowcast'?

Comment: Following your logic: "backcast" would sound right. Even if it's not a real word people should understand it.

Comment: I'm voting to close. There isn't sufficient context about the data or the process the scientists are using.  We are asked for a scientific answer so we need scientific details. (see my answer for a further explanation).

Comment: An estimate about candy-bar prices in 1850 is not a prediction. A prediction is a foretelling, i.e., telling beforehand.

Comment: I think it's simply an "estimate".

Comment: I've never heard hindcast or backcast.   You could say, for example: "Extrapolating back from [specify the data set], we estimate that [what you are trying to estimate]".  In general, if you are estimating something, call it an estimate.  If you have very little information upon which to make an estimate, you might call it a guesstimate.  Interpolating is correct only if you have data for the period before and the period after the time in question.

Comment: @moonman239 - Can you edit the question to convince me that this isn't just a plain old calculation?  In a prediction, you make an educated guess, and then as more information becomes available, you are able to compare your guess with the new information, and determine how good your guess was.  What would be the new information in your example?

Answer (score 1):

If a scientist makes an estimate about something in the past, we are talking about **a scientific...**

- **assessment** (noun) - assess (verb) -  "to determine the value, significance, or extent of." [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/assessing)
- **estimation** (noun) -  "a rough calculation of the value, number, quantity, or extent of something." [Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=estimation&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=0HLOVbG3HcOB8QfIjoCQBA&gws_rd=ssl)
- **evaluation** (noun) - "the making of a judgment about the amount, number, or value of something" [Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=estimation&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=0HLOVbG3HcOB8QfIjoCQBA&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=evaluation)

Comment: Where is the part that signifies past in any of these words?

Answer (score 1):

The term you need is "hindcast". Several threads in the replies need to be separated and clarified.

A forecast is an extrapolation; it uses past and present observations to predict the future. To take a simple example, if I give you the series of data from successive years as 2,4,6,8 ... you may reasonably extrapolate forwards to forecast that the next year's number is 10.

A hindcast (this is the term you are looking for) is also an extrapolation from a set of past observations to a time previous to those observations. For example, if I give you 15, 12, 9 for three years, you may reasonably extrapolate backwards to hindcast that in the previous two years the numbers were 21 and 18.

None of this is interpolation, which is the estimation of missing values from within a series. For example, in six years, the numbers were 21,23,?,?,29 and 31. You will reasonably predict by interpolation between the known values that the missing numbers are 25 and 27.

Comment: *retrodiction* is similar.

Comment: I looked up hindcast, and found, to my surprise, that it is a word used in In oceanography and meteorology.  Can you add to your answer a reference, and tell us what sciences the word is used in?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the term you are looking for is [interpolation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/interpolation?q=interpolation%20):

> - (Mathematics) The insertion of an intermediate value or term into a series by estimating or calculating it from surrounding known values. (ODO)

- To make an accurate estimate of the value of a candy bar in the past the 'scientist' needs to interpolate values that are known or are considered reliable such as inflation rate, historic trends of production costs and raw materials etc.

Comment: I believe that interpolation may not be the best option. Interpolate means approximating an unknown intermediate value from two neighbor known values. Extrapolation means extending.

Answer (score 0):

I think similarly to Josh but, in this case. I think it's probably an [extrapolation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/extrapolation?q=extrapolation%20).

Actually you are the only one who can tell us. We don't know what data the scientists are using.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a **retrospective investigation** or **retrospective survey**.

"retrospective" definition : *Looking back on or dealing with past events or situations*.